# Firebase Google Sign In not working in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import React from 'react';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import App from './testlogin';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebaseConfig';

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = app.auth();
const db = app.firestore();
const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  
export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
        const user = res.user;
        const query = await db
                      .collection("users")
                      .where("uid", "==", user.uid)
                      .get();
        if (query.docs.length === 0) {
            await db.collection("users").add({
                uid: user.uid,
                name: user.displayName,
                authProvider: "google",
                email: user.email,
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(err.message);
    }
};
```

This code accesses the google sign in method and should pop up a window, but I don't get anything when I click the button. I have been having difficulty with implementing Firebase in React Native and this is one of the examples. I need an example of easy Google sign in button in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use https://rnfirebase.io/ library (their docs are quite helpful).

Here are their instructions for Google Sign-in: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google.

According to them, you need to

- ensure the "Google" sign-in provider is enabled on the Firebase Console.
- also install @react-native-google-signin/google-signin',
- then "Before triggering a sign-in request, you must initialize the Google SDK using your any required scopes and the webClientId, which can be found in the android/app/google-services.json"

Finally, as because following:
*Starting April 2020, all existing applications using external 3rd party login services (such as Facebook, Twitter, Google etc) must ensure that Apple Sign-In is also provided.* - **You would also need to support iOS / and Apple Sign-in too.** (if are building app also for iOS).

**NOTE**: I also remember that I had to put both, SHA1 and SHA256 hashes in the Firebase Console as some Firebase services were not working without it.

How to find SHA hashes in Android for Firebase (signing with Keystore that will be used in production should be already configured):

*The debug signing certificate is optional to use Firebase with your app, but is required for Dynamic Links, Invites and Phone Authentication. To generate a certificate run*

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

*and copy the SHA1 and SHA256 from the debug key. This generates two variant keys. You can copy the 'SHA1' that belongs to the debugAndroidTest variant key option.*

Again, I recommend you to put both SHA hashes in Firebase Console.

Comment: I got same problem although I am using rnfirebase/auth